# How to setup transaction management with hibernate 6 and Spring Boot 3 / spring 6?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-orm

With Spring boot 2.7.X/Hibernate 5 I was able to do something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.somewhere.packages", 
entityManagerFactoryRef = "sessionFactory",
transactionManagerRef = "hibernateTransactionManager")
public class TransactionConfig {
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.somewhere.packages.model");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        sessionFactory.setMetadataSources(new CustomMetadataSource());
        ...
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Whats the equivalent with spring-boot 3/hibernate 6?

Comment: Unless you are doing multiple datasources you shouldn't need any configuration.

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer? I'm wondering the same thing...

Comment: I moved everything to application.properties. Wasn't able to find a good programmatic solution. There might be an answer for spring boot 3.1 / hibernate 6.2

Comment: can you add some more details about what issue you are facing exactly when you declare above in spring boot version 3.x.x